# Oracle P_cursor to V_cursor empty table

Tags: oracle, toad

I want to run filter but with 2 package since both getting different form of input in aspx

So I have this code , when I run it on Toad Oracle, it says error
I think I know the source of error is V_cursor, since I dont know how to store V_cursor on empty table

Can u guys help me please ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY GIA.Package_AUTOCOMPLETE IS

procedure get_model
    (      
       P_STRINGMODEL            IN  VARCHAR2
       ,P_STRINGMERK            IN  VARCHAR2          
       ,p_CURSOR                OUT Types.ref_cursor
       ,p_STATUS                OUT VARCHAR2
       ,p_ERROR_MESSAGE         OUT VARCHAR2   
    )
is
BEGIN
 PACKAGE_AUTOCOMPLETE.GET_MERK
            (
            P_STRINGMERK        
           ,V_CURSOR              
           ,p_STATUS            
           ,p_ERROR_MESSAGE     
            )

Open P_CURSOR FOR
select * from V_CURSOR
WHERE V_CURSOR.MODEL_NAME = P_STRINGMODEL
       
        
        ;
       
        p_status := '1';
        p_error_message := 'ok';
EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                p_status := '0';
                p_error_message := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100);

    END get_model;

procedure get_merk
    (     
       P_STRINGMERK         IN VARCHAR2
       ,p_CURSOR                OUT Types.ref_cursor
       ,p_STATUS                OUT VARCHAR2
       ,p_ERROR_MESSAGE         OUT VARCHAR2   
    )
is
BEGIN
        open        p_cursor for
        SELECT MERK_ID, MERK_NAME, TYPE_NAME, MODEL_NAME, MODEL_DESC  
        FROM TABLE_MERK_MODEL
            WHERE MERK_ID=P_STRINGMERK
        ;
       
        p_status := '1';
        p_error_message := 'ok';
EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                p_status := '0';
                p_error_message := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100);

    END get_merk;

end package_AUTOCOMPLETE ;
/
```

Comment: so, what is the error message? The cursor declaration doesn't look like PLSQL syntax to me, so I guess the error is there.

Comment: i dont know how to store cursor into something

Comment: The local variable `v_cursor` does not seem to be declared anywhere.  You can't "store a cursor into something".  The only thing you can do with a cursor is fetch data from it.  You can't apply a `where` clause to a cursor.  I suppose you could take the cursor returned by `get_merk`, fetch the data into a local collection, iterate through the collection to exclude the rows you want to exclude, and then open `p_cursor` by selecting from that local collection.  But that's sufficiently complicated that I'd want to take a step back and determine if that's really the best architecture.

Comment: Yes I don't know how to declare v_cursor into something. Can it be declared as idk table ?
I can't find it anywhere (V_cursor is TABLE) @JustinCave

Comment: Declaring the cursor is when you create the local variable.  Presumably of type `Types.ref_cursor`.  In your last comment, you seem to be indicating that you expect `v_cursor` to be a table type which doesn't make sense.  Declaration is completely separate from operating on the local variable which you can't realistically do in the way you appear to want.  I'm not sure what an "idk table" is.